# Can't remove space from string

Tags: php, string, file-io

I have an array filled with elements taken from a file named "words.txt". After accessing the first element of the array, I can't seem to modify it for use elsewhere. I'm simply trying to remove a space from the element I'm accessing, but even after using `str_replace()`, it echos with a space.

```
$words = file("words.txt");

$domain = "www." . $words[0] . ".com";
$domain = str_replace(' ', '', $domain);

echo $domain;
```

What is the simple thing I'm missing here?

Comment: `var_dump($words)` and see what you are getting.

Comment: Always best to var_dump your data for us to see, as well as the actual output your getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file` by default leaves in the **line endings** (e.g. `\n`). Line breaks render merely as spaces in HTML. You either need to `str_replace("\n", ..)`, or use [`file(.., FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`](http://php.net/file).